# iOS 11 Document Based App template - remove sidebar browser.

Tags: xcode, ios11, swift4, uidocumentinteractioncontroller

Is it possible to eliminate the sidebar browser (location/favorites/tags) in a document based app? The goal is that users can only access files created on my app [![][1]][1]

Comment: This is very similar to your other question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48228776/ios-11-document-based-using-only-for-my-app-files.  As far as I can see there is no way to remove it.

Comment: Yep, also mine! : )

Comment: You shouldn't really ask two questions that are so close to each other but really close one and ask everything in the other.

Comment: It’s for clarity, they are 2 different questions

Comment: Not possible yet. Please file a bug at bugreport.apple.com. (But it would probably be a bad idea: what if one of your files is for example sent by email and then saved in a different folder? How would the user access it?)

Comment: Is there a way to customize a document-based app?