# Customize iOS11 Document Based App Template

Tags: xcode, ios11, swift4, nsdocumentcontroller

I need to do the following customizations on the provided iOS 11 Document Based App Template:

- A library with only my App files, as Procreate example App bellow
- Get rid of the sidebar browser, so I have a fullscreen that shows only my library.
  https://assets.procreate.art/video/home/mp4/block-10.mp4

I have asked Apple Code Level suport but still haven't got an answear. Can someone please help?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a combination of you're other two questions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48228776/ios-11-document-based-using-only-for-my-app-files & here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48233085/ios-11-document-based-app-template-remove-sidebar-browser.  You stated they were two different questions so don't then combine them into one.

Comment: You are not going to be able to achieve what you want using a document based app.  That video of Procreate looks more like a custom UICollectionView.

Comment: They are 2 different questions, but as the only answer I got was from you requesting to merge into a single one I did so...  btw, do you know the answear?

Comment: Cool.  As I said I don't think you can do it using a document based app.  You can't remove the sidebar or restrict it to viewing just your app.  I think you will have to go a more customised solution.  That video looks like a UICollectionView.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth thanks for the info! Are you sure that it’s not possible to customize it? Or it’s your guess? I could built it with UICollectionView but the template would save a lot of development time

Comment: Well I would never say 100% but I can't see any properties that allow that functionality, I can't find anything about doing it in the Apple documentation or on Google.  So I'm confident enough that if I was to need to do something like that I wouldn't use it.

Comment: Makes sense, that is also my conclusion... going to start from scratch then! Thanks again!

Comment: What sidebar browser are you talking about?